# Postgres docker instance doesn't persist state after restart

Tags: postgresql, docker

I pulled and run the postgres official image from docker-hub. Everything works but the problem is when i stop and start the container all data is lost and instance returns to a clean state, while i'm expecting data to be persisted on  the instance self storage.

i don't want to use external volumes in order to keep the instance self contained.

is this a configuration issue?

Answer (score 1):

Yes: you need to use external volumes (either native Docker volumes or host directories), that's not really optional.  Deleting and recreating containers is *extremely* routine (you need to do it to take a security patch in the database software or surrounding Linux distribution infrastructure if nothing else) and if you delete a container you lose all of the data that was in it.

A typical PostgreSQL invocation would look like

```
docker run \
  --name postgres \
  -d \
  -p 5432:5432 \
  -v $PWD/pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
  postgres:11
```

https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/ lists out all of the environment variables and container filesystem paths that are interesting to a typical user.